# Postgres - Fast way to sum over rows from last day of month

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql, date

I want to query a table and sum a column for all of the rows from the last day of the month.

Let's use the following table as an example:

```
CREATE TABLE example(dt date, value int)
```

(The real table has many more columns and is relatively large, and the real query is more complicated)

I have the following query:

```
SELECT dt, SUM(value)
FROM example
WHERE dt IN  (SELECT DISTINCT
     date_trunc('MONTH', generate_series('2012-01-01'::date,
                                         '2016-12-01'::date,
                                         interval '1 day') + INTERVAL '1 MONTH - 1 day')::date)
GROUP BY dt
```

It runs in about ~2 seconds on my real table.

However, if I generate the full list of end-of-month days in my range and parameterise the query like so:

```
SELECT dt, SUM(value)
FROM example
WHERE dt IN ('2012-01-31', ...)
GROUP BY dt
```

It's much quicker, ~750ms.

I would prefer not to generate the dates and pass them through to the query like that, is there a way I can do this entirely in SQL and make it as fast as the latter version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sub-select is needlessly complicated. It can be simplified to:

```
SELECT dt, SUM(value)
FROM example
WHERE dt IN (SELECT d::date
             from generate_series('2012-01-01'::date, '2016-12-01'::date, interval '1 month') dates (d)
GROUP BY dt;  --<< the group by is necessary
```

Maybe that speeds up the query.

You can also try to put the date generation into a CTE:

```
with dates (d) as (
  SELECT t::date
  from generate_series('2012-01-01'::date, '2016-12-01'::date, interval '1 month') t
)
SELECT dt, SUM(value)
FROM example
WHERE dt IN ( select d from dates)
GROUP BY dt;
```

Sometimes doing a JOIN is also more efficient:

```
with dates (d) as (
  SELECT t::date
  from generate_series('2012-01-01'::date, '2016-12-01'::date, interval '1 month') t
)
SELECT dt, SUM(value)
FROM example
  JOIN dates on example.dt = dates.d
GROUP BY dt;
```

Comment: Here's the query I actually used: `SELECT dt, SUM(value)
FROM example
WHERE dt in (select date_trunc('month', d) + interval '1 month - 1 day'
                    from generate_series('2012-01-01'::date, '2016-11-10'::date, interval '1 month') dates(d))`

Answer (score 0):

The performance problem in your query comes from the fact that you are generating a daily series. Change it to monthly, remove the `distinct` and add a `group by`

```
select dt, sum(value)
from
    example
    inner join (
       select date_trunc('month', dt) + interval '1 month - 1 day' as dt
       from generate_series('2012-01-01'::date, '2016-12-01', '1 month') gs (dt)
    ) d using (dt)
group by dt
```